# Zend Framework 2 Forms

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2, zend-form

I have a simple question about ZF2. Why when and send a post to another method my post data is changed. I mean :

```
<input name="auth.mode" type="text"/>
<input name="block.seconds" type="text" />
```

It suppose get :

```
array(2) {
  ["auth.mode"] => string(1) "A"
  ["block.seconds"] => string(0) "12"
}
```

But I get :

```
array(2) {
  ["auth_mode"] => string(1) "A"
  ["block_seconds"] => string(0) "12"
}
```

I do not need my keys changed. I need my keys as in the HTML form with this name. Help please.

Comment: I guess you should not write plain-text form if you're using Zend Framework. You probalby should use the built-in methods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PHP is making this change, not ZF. You can't have dots in the `$_POST` etc. array key names, so PHP automatically converts them to underscores.

Comment: Thanks Tim. Nice clarification about it.